# URL Pattern with Primary Key not working properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-urls

Need help with the regex in urls. I'm building a different app, not the one shown in the lecture above. To relate to my case with the lecture, School is Clients, and Students is categories.

In urls.py file, from url_patterns :

`url(r'^(?P<pk>[-\w]+)/$', views.DetailClientList.as_view(), name='Detail_Client_List'),`

This work correctly, with the address being http://127.0.0.1:8000/App1/cli1/, where cli1 is a Clients table primary key (one of the records).

But when I put the line below in url patterns (instead of the above)

`url(r'^<str:pk>/$', views.DetailClientList.as_view(), name='Detail_Client_List')`

I get the following error (same error for int:pk):

---

Page not found (404)

Request Method:GET

Request URL:http://127.0.0.1:8000/App1/cli1/

---

The resulting URL is the same in both cases described above. So where am I going wrong here. I'm guessing its an issue with the url pattern regex (although resulting URL is the same?).

Please help. TIA!

Comment: use 'path' instead of 'urls', path('<str:pk>/', views.DetailClientList.as_view(), name='Detail_Client_List')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with `re_path` instead of 'url'

```
from django.urls import re_path, path
```

1. re_path

```
re_path(r'^<str:pk>/$', views.DetailClientList.as_view(), name='Detail_Client_List')
```

2. path

```
path('<str:pk>/', views.DetailClientList.as_view(), name='Detail_Client_List')
```

Comment: Both the above seem to work for ```r'^(?P<pk>[-\w]+)/$'```, but not for <str:pk>. (FYI My django version in 2.2.2)

Comment: you're getting error on `<str:pk>/`?. PS. append slash at end

Comment: Oh, this worked! Could you please explain what the error was, and what happened? Ty!
In the error, the ```/``` was automatically added at the end, so I thought it really wasn't an issue

Comment: you have to add slash at the end or you have to write `APPEND_SLASH = True` in `settings.py`. For more info - https://www.morethanseven.net/2009/02/10/append-slashes-urls-django/  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You might misunderstood the [***`url(...)`***--(Doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/#url) with [***`path(...)`***--(Doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urls/#path)

So,

```
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns = [
    url(
        r'^(?P<pk>[-\w]+)/$',
        views.DetailClientList.as_view(),
        name='Detail_Client_List'
    ),
]
```

is identical with the following,

```
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path(
        '<str:pk>',
        views.DetailClientList.as_view(),
        name='Detail_Client_List'
    )
]
```